# Wireshark 1.99 monitor mode?

Tags: macos, wireshark, monitoring, network-monitoring

Relatively new to Wireshark, running 1.99.7 on a MacBook Pro (2015), OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.  I have no problem with basic capture via wifi, but have been unable to figure out how to turn on monitor mode.

I've read the various guides and posts, most of which reference an Edit Interface Settings window that doesn't seem to exist in 1.99.  The Capture Options window seems similar, and there is a Capture section in the preferences page, but neither of those have anything regarding monitoring.

The only thing I've found that has potential is a line under Preferences > Advanced that's called capture.devices_monitor_mode.  If it were a Boolean, I would just change it to True, but it's a String, so I'm not sure how to configure the string to show that I want the wifi chip to be in monitor mode.

Thanks in advance for the help; the ask.wireshark is rejecting any new signups right now for some reason.

Comment: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/26270/how-to-turn-on-monitor-mode-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Hi ssnobody, and thanks for the pointer, but unfortunately that page is discussing version 1.10 from about 2 years ago.  The options it mentions no longer exist in that location in version 1.99.